# unable to update min-width of cdk-connected-overlay

Tags: angular, angular5, overlay, angular-template, angular-cdk

I am using template refrence variable for this component. Here is how I have created an overlay for dropdown options

```
<ng-template
cdk-connected-overlay
[minWidth]="optionsWidth"
[open]="isOpen"
[origin]="origin"
#optionsContainer
>

<div class="options">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

even after minwidth value is updated , the width of cdkconnectedoverlay doesn't change

I tried to update it using overlay ref below is the code

```
@ViewChild('optionsContainer')
  optionsContainer: CdkConnectedOverlay;
```

next i read the overlayref

```
this.optionsContainer.overlayRef
```

but this is always undefined, stuck with this can anyone help I am using angular cdk 5.XX version

Answer (score 1):

`overlayRef` will only exist once the overlay is attached.
You can subscribe to the `attach` event to determine when it's attached and then apply the width you want.

`this.optionsContainer.attach.subscribe(() => {
    // update width here
})`

Answer (score 0):

add positionChange attribute and try code:

this.optionsContainer.overlayRef.updateSize({minWidth: this.optionsWidth})